# Image not loading facing issue

Tags: reactjs, vite

```
export const Image = {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  bgHome: require("../Image/bg.jpeg"),
};
```

```
<img src={Image?.bgHome} loading="lazy" />
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.
> Facing issue like these.

Background image not loading.

Comment: How are you running your project? There is no `require()` function in the browser. It's part of the "CommonJS" module standard, and it's only available on the server side (Node.js, Bun, Deno, etc). Some "bundlers," like Webpack, let you use `require()` in your source code, but Webpack compiles it away and replaces it with the path to the image in the CDN. You're probably not using Webpack or a build system. Frameworks like Next.js automatically include Webpack for you. More reading: [Webpack, When to Use and Why](https://andrewray.me/blog/webpack-when-to-use-and-why).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Vite` and 'ReactJS' the 'require' syntax wont work. This is CommonJS and if you want to do it in React, you need to use the `import` keyword. It will be something like

```
import bgImage from "../Image/bg.jpeg";

<img src={bgImage} loading="lazy" />
```

You can also check out the Vite documentation [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets)